# Serial connection test "io invalid library identifier" Staubli Robotics Suite

Tags: serial

I took this VAL3 code off the Staubli technical database to test the serial connection of my 2 ports. Basically, it sends 25 data frames to do an average, resulting in a Char/s value. Here is the code:

```
begin

 bEnd = false
 sTestSpeed = "0123456789"
 io:portSerial1=sTestSpeed
 sReceive = io:portSerial2
 nTimer=clock()

 for i=0 to 24
   io:portSerial1=sTestSpeed
   sReceive=io:portSerial2
 endfor

 nTimeOneChar(clock()-nTimer)//(25*30*9)
 gotoxy(11,11)
 put(round (1/nTimeOneChar)
 put("Char/s")
 bEnd = true

end
```

I'm running into the error

> 'io:' Invalid library identifier

I'm not sure whether I should be pasting in a physical path/link wherever I use `io:portSerial1` and `io:portSerial2`. Or, should I be downloading a specific library for this?

Answer (score 0):

The IO library was used in VAL version 6 and earlier. it was a system created and maintained library of all IO found on the system. starting with VAL 3 version 7 we directly access the IO hardware using variables in the application.

Assuming your system is running version 7, you need to create a sio variable to use in place of io:portSerial1. Link the value of the variable to serial port. If you are editing this code in SRS, make sure you have the serial ports enabled in the controller configuration. by default they are disabled. while actual serial ports on PC are rare these days, if your PC has serial ports SRS will take them over.